# Hide parts of the page

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I'm creating a blog on Wordpress and I want to have a system of membership where people can see a bit of an article like here :

http://www.lemonde.fr/entreprises/article/2016/05/08/la-lente-revolution-du-car-longue-distance_4915637_1656994.html

http://www.revmed.ch/rms/2016/RMS-N-513/Comprendre-les-immunodeficiences-primaires-utilite-d-un-registre

with a box underneath to log in or sign up.

[image: like here the box, total access is hidden, buy the article or subscribe.]

I found many answers to hide all the page but not a bit.
Any solutions ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `wp_trim_words()`. For a quick example, add the following to the theme `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'trim_page');
function trim_page($content)
{
    return wp_trim_words($content, 50, '...');
}
```